# NodeJS Cluster Error : SIGSEGV

Tags: node.js

I use nodejs cluster

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
   for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++){
      var worker = cluster.fork();
      worker.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
        console.log("worker was killed by signal: " + signal);
      });
   }
}
```

And sometimes with different time intervals i have a error

```
worker was killed by signal: SIGSEGV
```

What this error mean and why she called?
node version v0.11.14-pre, Debian

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564372/what-causes-a-sigsegv This might help you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly the answer but think this could help.

Using `phantomJs` I was getting *sometimes* the same error (changing worker for signal). The situation: I was opening a page using phantomJs; when the body was ready I want a callback to be called, then I was closing phantom. grosso modo my code was:

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ...
  callbackDone(result);
  ph.exit();
});
```

Doing so, the exception was:

```
 signal killed phantomjs: SIGSEGV
```

At this point I realized it was breaking **just** for heavy callback tasks. In order words, if the callback function before `exit()` was a light one: everything was fine; but in different conditions it crashes.

The solution: close the object before the callback:

```
  ph.exit();
  callbackDone(result);
```