# Runtime error in SPOJ

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I just started with competitive programming. I am kinda stuck with this prime no. generator problem on SPOJ. Code works fine on GeeksforGeeks IDE but on SPOJ it gives a **runtime error**. The question goes like this:

Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!

Input:
The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output:
For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

Example

```
Input:
2
1 10
3 5

Output:
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

and my solution is this:

```
# include<iostream>
# include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    int up,low;
    cin>>low>>up;
    int len = 1000000;
    bool arr[len];
    arr[1]=arr[0]=false;
    for(int i=2;i<=up;i++)
        arr[i]=true;

    for(int i=2;i<sqrt(up);i++) {
        if(arr[i]==true){
            for(int j=(i*i);j<=up;j+=i){
                arr[j]=false;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=low;i<=up;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==true)
            cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    if(t==1)
        cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

I have used Sieve of Eratosthenes to solve this problem.

Comment: Well `bool arr[len];` is not legal C++, that might be your problem. `bool arr[1000000];` would be OK.

Comment: You should describe the error you are getting in more detail. "it gives a runtime error" is a little vague ;-)

Comment: `bool arr[1000000];` could be a Stack Overflow.. Better use a `std::vector`

Comment: You could define `len` as `const int` or `constexpr`, which would be better.  However, the array is huge for the stack.  You should declare it as `static` or move it outside `main`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/9254539. Your code only compiles because of a GCC non-standard extension, and allocating a large array on the stack like this could cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your response! A great first experience at stack overflow :)
now coming back to the problem ;) 
I tried all of your suggested approaches but the SPOJ compiler still gives a run time error (SIGSEGV  @sebrockm  ;-)) .

Comment: The suggestion given by @ThomasMatthews worked well for all the test cases which i gave on https://ideone.com/ . But again it gave a SIGSEGV on SPOJ.

Comment: Using vectors again resulted in a runtime error @drescherjm

Comment: Sometimes, a SIGSEGV on SPOJ means that you need to use a different algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The [SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564372/what-is-sigsegv-run-time-error-in-c) is well known in C++. It means that you are trying to access memory that you are not allowed to access. In your particular case it is very likely* that you try to access `arr` with a wrong index.

As you initialized it as `bool arr[100000];` writing code like `arr[i]` is **only** valid for `0 <= i <= 99999`. Now look at your `for` loops, e.g. the first one

```
for(int i=2;i<=up;i++)
    arr[i]=true;
```

Whenever you enter a number for `up` that is greater than `99999`, you are causing undefined behavior here (most likely a SIGSEGV).

So you have to redesign your algorithm to store your boolean values, indicating if a number is prime, somehow differently.

* Note: I cannot be entirely sure if this is your issue because you didn't say for what input values of `up` and `low` this error occurs. When asking a question you should give as many infos as possible that allow to reproduce your issue.