# Android error: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) leads to app crash

Tags: java, android

I have developed Android phone app. Sometimes the app gets crashed without any warning. I couldn't find anything in logcat. Like the error in the code. What I get is

`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 3209 (Binder:3158_1)`

Since I am new to Android, I don't know exactly what is going wrong. What I ask for is, how can I debug this error? Are there any Android traces to look further into this?

I know that I didn't provide the code but there is no specific error shown in the logcat. How can I look for the bug?

Comment: If you actually aren't able to trace the crash  I suggest using some crash analytics you can trace it like, fabric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a debugger and query more information about the crash (e.g. LLDB). Sometimes you do not even need to set up breakpoints, since the debugger can stop when it catches an error and show you the problematic code (It can be on the native side).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564372/what-causes-a-sigsegv), bad memory access can lead to SIGSEGV.

Watch out for memory leaks in your app, make sure you are not holding any references to killed Context objects and etc.

Comment: Even though, it not the answer. I has some help to look forward. Thanks man :)