# Using MapBox to start Navigation UI causes unexpected crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am attempting to implement a navigation component to my application following this MapBox guide:

***https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/***

When I attempt to call `.startNavigation(...)` I get an unexpected error:

```
2020-03-08 19:51:45.786 11394-11394/com.example.mapboxnav A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 11394 (mple.mapboxnav), pid 11394 (mple.mapboxnav)
```

Since the application I'm creating features many buttons, I've implemented `View.OnClickListener` and am calling the Navigation interface when a user presses the navigation button (`R.id.startNav`). However, as soon as a user presses the button the application crashes.

The `currentRoute` is working and shown on the map upon calling `getRoute`, like the [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/assets/tutorials--android-navigation-sdk--calculate-and-draw-route-480-db6d930123f37f85adcf1bbd73870001.webp). I have verified that `currentRoute` is definitely not `null`. I have also attempted to start navigation with different coordinates without any luck.

`currentRoute` contains a route from the user's current/last known location to a specified destination. For reference, the line is set/generated with the following method:

```
public void initLine(Double lng, Double lat) {
        Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();
        Point origin = Point.fromLngLat(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
        Point destination = Point.fromLngLat(lng, lat);
        getRoute(origin, destination);

    }
```

**onClick:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            ...

            case R.id.startNav:

                boolean simulateRoute = true;

                NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                        .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                        .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                        .build();
                NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options); // Causes Crash

        }
    }
```

Comment: What other info is there about the crash? There should be more information in the Android Studio logcat when the app crashes. Search for the word `FATAL` and/or `Mbgl`.

Comment: @langsmith There is no more information. The error I specified is the only one that appears.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your build.gradle (app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend two and a half days over this until I discovered that the problem is that we need to set the location Engine before calling :

NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);

so your code should look like this and it should work:

```
NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                            .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                            .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                            .build();
    
    
// Just add these three lines
MapboxNavigation navigation = new MapboxNavigation(DriveActivity.this, getString(R.string. mapbox_access_token));
navigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);              mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().setLocationComponentEnabled(true);


NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
```

Let me know how it goes

Criss

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, very strange. I still feel like there's gotta be more info buried in the logcat. Maybe well above the `Fatal signal 11` line? Maybe, just maybe, it's related to `Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();`. Add a null check for `lastKnownLocation` and put

```
    Point origin = Point.fromLngLat(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
    Point destination = Point.fromLngLat(lng, lat);
    getRoute(origin, destination);
```

inside of the null check block?

Maybe you're using the wrong classes? Look at the Nav SDK's `NavigationLauncher` test app activity: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L342-L347. It's using `NavigationLauncherOptions.Builder`, whereas you aren't.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/NavigationLauncherActivity.java#L365

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions however I still have no luck. In regards to the error, unfortunately that it still the only one that appears. I have thoroughly looked through the logcat

Comment: So strange. Do you see what I mean about different builder classes being used when comparing test app to your code? Have you looked into that? Try copying over what's in the test app to your code...

Comment: I see what you mean. However I'm pretty sure that's the old version of the dependency. Utilising the object has changed as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score -1):

A `SIGSEGV` error is thrown when you attempt to access memory incorrectly or are accessing a piece of memory that is not allotted for your use. See [What causes a SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564372/what-causes-a-sigsegv) for more information on this.

The fact that the error occurs on the line below,

```
NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
```

leads me to believe that `NavigationLauncherOptions options` is not being assigned correctly and is possibly `NULL` causing you to derefrence a null pointer.

I know this isn't a perfect answer and doesn't really provide a solution to your problem, but I hope it helps bring you closer to finding an answer.

Here are some links that may help(including documentation):
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/1529
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/